# Change div order based on operating system

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to change div order based on operating system.

For example on windows

```
<div class="first"> </div>
<div class="second"> </div>
<div class="third"> </div>
```

on Mac

```
<div class="third"> </div>
<div class="first"> </div>
<div class="second"> </div>
```

I have some this js to show and hide a div which is okay if I use a parent div but I would rather reorder.

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") > -1) {
    $('#windows').hide();
    $('#mac').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a more general solution, you could store the order for each platform in an array and then go through the array and re-add the element to the container using `$.appendTo()`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b6uhw/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="first">1</div>
    <div class="second">2</div>
    <div class="third">3</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var macOrder = [".third", ".first", ".second"];

$(function () {
    var container = $('#container');
    for (var i = 0; i < macOrder.length; i++) {
        $(macOrder[i]).appendTo(container);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac") > -1) {
    $('.third').insertBefore('.first');
}
```

There is also `.insertAfter()` that you can use. I would use these methods for basic reordering like that seen in your example. If there is a lot of re-ordering required, I think a different approach may be better, like @Daniel's example